# When should a method return a new object instead of a reference in Java?

Tags: java, object, reference

Let's take this sample Person class from which we want to return the "Details"

```
public class Person() {
    private Details details;
...
```

When should I do this:

```
return new Details(this.details);
```

Instead of this:

```
return this.details;
```

Comment: ... When you want a new object instead of a reference to an existing one?  It's not really clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @David for example, in terms of good practices, when should I not return the reference?

Comment: If the class is immutable, that is, the data in it cannot be changed, then its always safe to pass that object around. If the data in the object can be changed and that's not desirable, you might consider passing a copy of the object (or switch to using immutable classes).

Comment: lets say you have a player, that player has a `Point` (a class of 2 floats) representing position, if you wanted to summon a projectile from that position, would you want to give it a reference or a copy? if you give it a reference, then when that projectile moves the player moves with it (because they are both sharing the same `Point` in memory)

Comment: Terminology nit-picking: it's Java.  You can't return "an object", only "a reference to an object".  `return new Details(...)` allocates a Details and returns a reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is best not to return references to objects unless they and their fields (and their fields) are immutable.  Consider this example:

```
class Foo {
    private int[] array = new int[];
    public int[] getArray() {
       return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }
}
```

This makes a `defensive copy` of the returned information so the user may not change the original.  If you simply returned the array reference the internals of the array and thus the `Foo` instance could be altered.

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on your use case. In a regular `getter` case, you'd just return the `this.details` reference.

I am assuming the constructor to which you are passing the `this.details` reference is meant to be a copy constructor that's supposed to shallow or deep copy the object (please clarify if that's not what you meant). You'd want to copy if you don't want the user of your method to make changes to your object but to work with a separate copy (how separate depends upon the depth of your copy).